# Finding the UMVUE of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I have been given the pdf:

$$f_X (x; \lambda) = \left(\frac{\lambda}{\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} x^{-\frac{3}{2}} e^{-\frac{\lambda}{x}} $$

with support $x>0$ and $\lambda>0$.

I am asked to find the UMVUE.

Now my current progress is by first observing that the likelihood function is of the form

$$a(\lambda)b(x)e^{c(\lambda)\times \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_i}}$$

and thus 
$$S(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_i}$$
is a complete, sufficient statistic.

Moreover, since $\frac{1}{X_i}$ follows a $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\lambda})$ distribution, then we  can easily see that 
$$S^*=\frac{2}{n}S$$
is an unbiased estimator.

Now Lehmann Scheffe theorem would say that $T^* = \mathbb{E}(S^* | S) $ is the UMVUE  but this seems too hard to compute... Any ideas?

Comment: $x>0$ edited the question - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d with pdf $$f_X(x;\lambda)=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}}e^{-\lambda/x}x^{-3/2}\mathbf1_{x>0}\quad,\,\lambda>0$$

By Lehmann-Scheffe theorem, an unbiased estimator of $1/\lambda$ based on a complete sufficient statistic would be the UMVUE of $1/\lambda$. You have found a complete sufficient statistic $T=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{X_i}$.

And since $E\left(\frac{1}{X_1}\right)=\frac{1}{2\lambda}$, we have $$E(T)=\sum_{i=1}^n E\left(\frac{1}{X_i}\right)=\frac{n}{2\lambda}$$

This itself shows the UMVUE must be $\frac{2}{n}T$.

Note that $E\left(\frac{2}{n}T\mid T\right)=\frac{2}{n}E(T\mid T)=\frac{2}{n}T$, so this step is redundant.

Comment: Thanks alot! If I happen to know that a statistic is unbiased, complete and sufficient then is it automatically a UMVUE or do I have to apply the Lehman Scheffe theorem?

Comment: I did apply Lehmann-Scheffe when I say that if a statistic is unbiased, complete and sufficient, then it is UMVUE. Suppose $g(T)$ is unbiased for $g(\theta)$ where $T$ is complete sufficient. Then $E(g(T)\mid T)=g(T)$ is the UMVUE of $g(\theta)$ by Lehmann-Scheffe.

Comment: Oh okay, so this would just generalise if the Lehmann Scheffe step is, as you said, redundant.

Comment: It is just a corollary of the theorem.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for your assistance!